# How to trigger a build in Jenkins After the success of other build but running in Bamboo

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

I am building two functional selenium test scripts from Jenkins that I want to trigger the test to run automatically once the build release of the project is done.

The project is running on Bamboo, I am looking for any way that Bamboo can notify Jenkins about the result "in my case must be success" and then my get test scripts to run automatically

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add task in your Bamboo build to run wget or curl command which will trigger Jenkins build: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/